# CANNOT Add one more action under Application Module in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

In the ZendSkeletonApplication in IndexController, I have added two more actions loginAction(), dashboardAction()

```
    class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            return new ViewModel();
           // Want to display Login Form
        }

        public function loginAction()
        {
            // Perform login action and redirect to dashboard Action
        }
        public function dashboardAction()
        {
            // Dashboard page
        }
    }
```

I have also created login.phtml and dashboard.phtml files

But If I route to localhost.zendapp/login or localhost.zendapp/dashboard none of the pages are found with error Page Not Found

Also, Module.php

```
        class Module
        {
            public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
            {
                $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
                $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
                $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
            }

            public function getConfig()
            {
                return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
            }

            public function getAutoloaderConfig()
            {
                return array(
                    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                        'namespaces' => array(
                            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                        ),
                    ),
                );
            }
         }
```

And module.config.php ( Same as in Sekeleton)

```
                return array(
                    'router' => array(
                        'routes' => array(
                            'home' => array(
                                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                        'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
                            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
                            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
                            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
                            'application' => array(
                                'type'    => 'Literal',
                                'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/application',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                                        'action'        => 'index',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'may_terminate' => true,
                                'child_routes' => array(
                                    'default' => array(
                                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                                        'options' => array(
                                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                                            'constraints' => array(
                                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            ),
                                            'defaults' => array(
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'service_manager' => array(
                        'abstract_factories' => array(
                            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
                            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
                        ),
                        'factories' => array(
                            'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'translator' => array(
                        'locale' => 'en_US',
                        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
                            array(
                                'type'     => 'gettext',
                                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'controllers' => array(
                        'invokables' => array(
                            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'view_manager' => array(
                        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
                        'display_exceptions'       => true,
                        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
                        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
                        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
                        'template_map' => array(
                            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
                            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
                            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
                            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
                        ),
                        'template_path_stack' => array(
                            __DIR__ . '/../view',
                        ),
                    ),
                    // Placeholder for console routes
                    'console' => array(
                        'router' => array(
                            'routes' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                );
```

Comment: there will be some problem with your routing. please check your module.config.php

Comment: Its same as in Sekeleton App. I have printed that also above.

Comment: Try adding different route instead of depending on child routes... That should work..

Comment: We have 'home' route for default IndexController in Application module. Do we need to add it again ?

Comment: nope. Let me add in answers... you can see there clearly

Answer (score 0):

I added route for login and dashboard actions.

```
return array(
                        'router' => array(
                            'routes' => array(
                                'home' => array(
                                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'login' => array(
                                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/login',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action'     => 'login',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'dashboard' => array(
                                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/dashboard',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action'     => 'dashboard',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                )                                    
                            ),
                        ),
                        'service_manager' => array(
                            'abstract_factories' => array(
                                'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
                                'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
                            ),
                            'factories' => array(
                                'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'translator' => array(
                            'locale' => 'en_US',
                            'translation_file_patterns' => array(
                                array(
                                    'type'     => 'gettext',
                                    'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                                    'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        'controllers' => array(
                            'invokables' => array(
                                'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
                            ),
                        ),
                        'view_manager' => array(
                            'display_not_found_reason' => true,
                            'display_exceptions'       => true,
                            'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
                            'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
                            'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
                            'template_map' => array(
                                'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
                                'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
                                'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
                                'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
                            ),
                            'template_path_stack' => array(
                                __DIR__ . '/../view',
                            ),
                        ),
                        // Placeholder for console routes
                        'console' => array(
                            'router' => array(
                                'routes' => array(
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    );
```